# To live in ignorance of just happiness

Tags: phrases, expression-choice

Is it a valid phrase? Please, accept or reject it. Maybe there is other exact expression.

Comment: today is a lucky day of down-voters :)

Comment: Could you give more context?  What concept are you trying to express, precisely?

Comment: Is there something in particular you are trying to fix? If not, this is a bit too much like proofreading.

Comment: @krubo for example, some countryman does not know about a beauties of city life, but (s)he lives in happiness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your phrase "to live in ignorance of just happiness" is grammatical but doesn't sound quite right.  "ignorance of X" means not knowing about X, but I don't think you mean "not knowing about just happiness".

Perhaps you are looking for the well-known English saying "Ignorance is bliss" and the corresponding idiomatic phrase "blissful ignorance".  For example, "I'd rather not tell my children about the famine in Somalia; they will be happier to live in blissful ignorance."

Comment: exactly. this is what I want to know.